# User Authentication for Identity Platform + API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

I have a Cloud Run service fronted by API Gateway. I would like to restrict access to some of the endpoints using JWTs.

[The only examples Google provides are these.](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt#configuring_apig_to_support_client_authentication)

I don't see an example for how to use Identity Platform here to authenticate users in API Gateway.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using the Firebase authentication method mentioned in the documentation works (i.e. add the `firebase` security definition).